# Issue with installing mongo db to azure function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure, azure-functions

I have issue with installation Mongo DB library in Azure Function. I can find, how to show console see on pic 2. I found some instructions [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHoXN.png), but it run on older interface of Azure, in my case I can't see it. I hope it's not restricted by free subscription.

Old instructions:

[image]

My case:

[image]

Comment: please use plain text instead images

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to add the `npm` packages manually you can do it using the terminal in the function app.
- The terminal will be under the `Advance tools`   tab under `developer tools` section. Just click on `go`.

[image]

- After that a new tab will open where your bash shell will be located.
  [image]
- Now just run the command to install the  `npm` packages.

```
npm install mongodb
```

Then restart the function.